# Dismissing Keyboard on Checkbox onCheckedChange Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-jetpack-compose, android-checkbox

I'm using Jetpack compose and I'm trying to dismiss the keyboard (which a TextField creates when it has focus) whenever I check the box.

I have something like:

```
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    Checkbox(
        checked = isChecked,
        onCheckedChange = { isChecked ->
            focusManager.clearFocus()
    })
```

However, I find that when I put my breakpoints, focusManager.clearFocus() isn't being consistently called whenever I am checking/unchecking the box.

Is there an easy way to dismiss the keyboard upon checking a box? Why is onCheckedChange not being called all the time?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mismatched the `isChecked` variable. That's why `onCheckedChange` is not triggered. Check the below composable function.

I have added one TextField. If you click on it, it will get the focus and will open the keyboard. In the checkbox, I have given the logic that if the checkbox is checked, it will close the keyboard if it's already opened.

```
@Composable
fun checkCheckbox() {
    val textFieldValue = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val isChecked = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        value = textFieldValue.value,
        onValueChange = { textFieldValue.value = it },
        label = { Text("Label") }
    )

    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    Checkbox(
        checked = isChecked.value,
        onCheckedChange = { checked ->
            Log.e("Check::", checked.toString())
            isChecked.value = checked

            if (checked) {
                Log.e("Focus::", "Clear")
                focusManager.clearFocus()
            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onCheckedChange` is a callback to be invoked when checkbox is being clicked.

If you want to dismiss the keyboard without clear the focus you can use `keyboardController?.hide()`:

```
var isChecked by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

Checkbox(
    checked = isChecked,
    onCheckedChange = { 
        isChecked = it
        keyboardController?.hide()

        //If you want to close the keyboard only if the checkbox is checked
        //if (it) { 
        //    keyboardController?.hide()
        //}
    })
```

If you want to dismiss the keyboard and clear the focus use:

```
Checkbox(
    checked = isChecked,
    onCheckedChange = { 
        isChecked = it
        focusManager.clearFocus()
    })
```

Comment: I was thinking how `onCheckedChange` is the callback whenever you are clicking on the checkbox. So it doesn't depend on `checked` and its value right? `onCheckedChange` should fire as you are clicking on the checkbox regardless.

Comment: @SmallGrammer Yes it doesn't depend on the value, it is just triggered when the value changes.